# \newcommand vs. \def (LaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX)

Tags: macros

I've been trying to understand what something like

```
\def\mapu#1#2#3{\overset{#1}{\underset{#2}{#3}}}
```

does, and it seems it does the same as

```
\newcommand{\mapu}[3]{\overset{#1}{\underset{#2}{#3}}}.
```

So the question is: is there any difference between the two, and which would you recommend?

Comment: There are many posts here about this. The main difference is that `\def` can override commands.

Comment: So the effect is the same only the distinction between \newcommand and \renewcommand is lost when using \def. OK.